# Reparametrization of an absolutely continuous curve

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces

If $\alpha : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n} $ is $C^1$ and $\alpha'(t) \neq 0$ for all $t\in[0,1]$ then there always exists a reparametrization in which $\| \alpha'(s) \| = 1$.

Is there an equivalent reparametrization if $y : [0,1] \rightarrow X$ if $X$ is a metric space and $y$ is absolutely continuous? I.e. if there exists the limit
$$ |\dot y(t)| := \lim_{u \rightarrow t} \dfrac{d(y(u),y(t))}{|u-t|} \neq 0$$
and for every $t<u$ it holds
$$d(y(t),y(u)) \leq \int_t^u |\dot y(r)| \, dr , $$
is it true that
$$ |\dot y(s)| = 1 $$
with a certain reparametrization?

If I try to emulate the argument in the smooth case I obtain
$$ s(t) := \int_0^t |\dot y(r)| \, dr $$
invertible, so I can write
$$|\dot y(s(t))| = \lim_{u \rightarrow t} \dfrac{d(y(s(u)),y(s(t)))}{|u-t|} = \lim_{u \rightarrow t} \dfrac{d(y(s(u)),y(s(t)))}{|s(u)-s(t)|}  \dfrac{|s(u)-s(t)|}{|u-t|}, $$
but can't reach a conclusion.

Comment: Is there a concept of derivatives in arbitrary metric spaces?

Comment: The one I'm using is $|\dot y(t)| := \lim_{u \rightarrow t} \dfrac{d(y(u),y(t))}{|u-t|}$

Comment: What you are asking for is called the metric derivative (speed) of a curve. See my videos here: https://youtu.be/1ldMQZv8B1k?t=509

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $L$ be the length of $y$. Let $\mu$ be the measure on $[0,1]$ associated with the weight $|\dot y|$. That is, $\mu(E)=\int_E |\dot y|$. 
Since this measure is absolutely continuous, there is a function $\phi:[0,L]\to [0,1]$ such that $\mu([0,\phi(s)]=s$ for every $s\in [0,L]$. Define $z(s)=y(\phi(s))$.

By construction, $z$ is $1$-Lipschitz: for $s<u$, 
$$d(z(u),z(s)) \le \int_{\phi(s)}^{\phi(u)} |\dot y| = 
\mu([\phi(u),\phi(s)]) = u-s $$

As $u\to s$,
$$\frac{d(z(u),z(s))}{u-s}
= \frac{d(z(u),z(s))}{\psi(u)-\psi(s)} \frac{\psi(u)-\psi(s)}{u-s} 
\to |\dot y(s)|^{-1} |\dot y(s)|=1
$$